# Process only the first file in each folder on S3 through Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a use case as described below -

1. An S3 bucket having a structure like `s3://bucket-name/level1/level2-01/filexx.txt`
2. There are 2000+ files on average in each `level2` folder.
3. Files are received on an ad-hoc basis (can be daily or weekly), i.e., with no predefined frequency.

I want to extract some metadata from `only the first file in each level2-xx` folder. For example, if I receive 2000 files in `level2-01`, and the first file is `file01.txt` - just process that. In `level2-02`, process file01.txt and then proceed to `level2-03`

**Possible Solutions:**

1. I can set up an [event notification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/EventNotifications.html) on the S3 bucket for each ObjectCreated action, and logically process the first file in each folder and do nothing for others. But it would trigger a lambda function for each file, i.e., 2000 lambda invocations for 2000 files.
2. Create an SQS queue and send event notifications from S3 to SQS. Next, setup a lambda trigger on the SQS queue, and use [Lambda event filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html) to invoke lambda only for specific filter patterns. I am not able to figure out a pattern that can just process the first file in each folder and reject the others.

Please suggest if there is any other way to achieve this or if there is a pattern I can use for #2 above.

Comment: Generally Lambda invocations that basically check the event data and return early will not cost you even a dollar over a year.

Comment: When you say that you want "only the first file", does it NEED to be the first file (listed alphabetically), or are you okay with ANY file (which might be the first one that has arrived in that directory)? Your possible solutions are all event-based -- does this mean you need the file as soon as it is available, or are you happy to run this program ONCE on all existing files that have arrived?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it can be ANY one file within the directory. The order does not matter. 
And yes, it has to be event based. Else, I could have run a lambda function to listen to an SQS queue and process a batch of files every 15 mins. If real time does not work, I would go with lambda SQS route.

Comment: Bear in mind the possibility of two Lambda functions being invoked concurrently, or close to, as a consequence of S3 objects appearing at a given prefix and both thinking they are dealing with the first object at the same prefix. If it's important to you that one and only one "first object" is processed then you'll need to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event notifications with a filter option on object key names. This will let you trigger lambda functions only for the specific files based on the configuration.

In the given scenario, the key **prefix** will be `level1/level2`, and the **suffix** will be `file01.txt`. This configuration will enable you to trigger the lambda function exclusively for the first text file in each level2 folder.

[image]

Comment: file01 was an example. The file names are not consistent across level2 folders.

Comment: If the file names are inconsistent, then you would need to invoke the lambda function for all files and let the lambda decide which file to process. IMO, it's better to apply the logic at the place of file generation, where you can easily create the first file with a unique name, and it would solve the lambda invocation for all incoming files.